# Glitchy Computer Screen and then Audio

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm not sure if this is the right website to talk about this, but here it goes.

When playing video games or high quality video for a long period of time, my computer starts to freeze and unfreeze randomly (frozen for 1 second at most). The audio gets distorted and if music is playing, it sometimes sounds like it has been slowed down to half speed or more. If I continue to play/watch, the computer will eventually completely freeze and sometimes bluescreen.

**Computer Specs:**

Intel i7 920

NVIDIA 550ti

6GB RAM

7200rpm Hard Drive

Comment: check the fans in the computer, esp the gfx card. Install a temp monitoring application and keep an eye on temps. Google "monitor computer temperature"

Comment: Checked for overheating problems and the results were all pointing to no. The graphics card would get up to 68C and start to "lag". The mouse would jerk around. Once I close the application (Minecraft in this case) it would still be very jerky and slow. As if it would crash any second. Restarting fixes this issue for 2-6 hours of (non continuous) use.

Comment: @Logman Any ideas?

Comment: maybe memory and/or pagefile, fragmentated hdd